# Chrome extension - load js contend dynamically to access current tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'am on popup script.

```
 $('#popup-content').load(chrome.extension.getURL("/src/popup/my.html") );
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "/src/popup/my.js"});
```

My `manifest.json`:

```
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon19.png",
    "default_popup": "/src/popup/my.html"
  },
```

The `my.html` loads itself well.
But `my.js` fails on load.

It fails as

> "Cannot read property 'query' of undefined"

The `my.js` part that fails is here:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
```

**Q:** So, how to execute `my.js` file to make it select current tab?

**UPDATE:**

I've fixed it like this:

Loading it using JQuery but not execute script:

```
$.getScript( chrome.extension.getURL("/src/popup/my.js"), (data, textStatus, jqxhr) => {});
```

And in `manifest.json` I've added this:

```
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'unsafe-eval';"
```

**But I still wonder wow to make correct/safe way.**

Comment: ok. I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157065/chrome-extension-wont-load-my-javascript-from-the-popup-file

Comment: but I still would like to know how to make it work in a save manner - without using "unsafe-eval"